# Memory issue after releasing the object

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

```
NSArray *imageExtension  = [info.ThemeImage componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[imageExtension objectAtIndex:0]ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
image=[image addImageReflection:0.50];

[CarouselView  setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-200, image.size.width, image.size.height)];

UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]init];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];

[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[image release];
```

After releasing  the object image still i do have memory leak...

I dont have any idea why its showing memory leak in instruments leak

Comment: is addImageReflection creating a second image object?

Answer (score 3):

There's three issues with the code above that would cause a memory leak.

First, you create the`image`here:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

You then assign that pointer`image`to something else, thereby losing the original reference:

```
image=[image addImageReflection:0.50];
```

`addImageReflection` I assume gives you an autoreleased object.

Despite this, you later release`image`:

```
[image release];
```

What you are releasing here is not the original pointer you allocated, but instead the later assigned autoreleased object. So you are creating a second problem by over releasing.

Finally, you have a third problem. The object`button`that you create here is never released:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 1):

you didn't release the button? If the code above is in a function and it was called many time button will leak.
try add

```
[button release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it same after you do?

```
[[self view] addSubview:button];
[button release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are allocing a new UIImage

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Here you are doing some action(reflection?) on image and probably this function returns an autoreleased instance..Here you are reassigning that instance to your original instance variable..You will lose reference to your original image instance and it will be leaked..Also you are having reference to an autoreleased instance

```
image=[image addImageReflection:0.50];
```

which you wrongly try to release afterwards, which will cause the crash..

```
[image release];
```